# SAPUI5 Using the same Controller for two Views

Tags: sapui5

I recently developed an SAPUI5 app for the Fiori Launchpad and am looking to convert the same app to also be Freestyle Portal usable and individually stylable, so I need a second View.

The problem is I have the task to use the same Logic aka. `Controller` for both Views. I've tried using routing, but I cant seem to find a solution, that's working for me, so I would welcome any suggestions how to tackle this task.

I am also really new to SAPUI5 so it might be that I am overlooking an easy solution so please be considerate.

With regards 
Mathias

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have already tried? If you are going to navigate from view to another, it would be difficult to reuse the same controller, if not, it is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the SAPUI5 SDK Documentation for the class sap.ui.core.mvc.controller method extend.

You could define a class based on the UI5 Standard sap.ui.core.mvc.controller using the extend method to create a controller that contains the common functions needed by both views. Then you could defined two controllers using extend on the common controller. Now you would have two controllers containing the common functions and have the possibility to add view specific functions.

Note that NO separate namespaces are created.

Here is the outline of the structure that you would create.

Common Controller: BaseController.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    ... //Other classes needed
], function (Controller, ..) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("yourApp.controller.BaseController", {
        someMethod: function () {
            ....
        },
    });
});
```

Specific Controller for one view
ViewOneController.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "yourApp/controller/BaseController",
    ... //Other classes needed
], function (myBaseController, ..) {
    "use strict";
    return myBaseController.extend("yourApp.controller.ViewOneController", {
        someMethod2: function () {
            ....
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was mostly what I was looking for, but I couldnt read that from the Documentation, brcause it is quite short. One Problem I've run into though is, that when I call the Child controller first it fails to load the Base Controller. Ive coded the extensions as you explained or are there extra steps to load the childcontroller first?

Comment: The framework should take care of loading the modules when needed. 

Check that the name of the files are correct and fully qualified.  What error do you get in the console?